# How can I select <div data-image='.....""> in python if I want to scraping image out with Python

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I am using Python to scraping some images from a website.
From that website, all images are using `<div data-image="https://......">` to store. How can I use Python(Beautiful Soup 4) to download the images? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This code is for downloading and saving images

```
import os
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "XXX"
html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

imgs = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"thumb-pic"})
 for img in imgs:
     imgUrl = img.a['href'].split("imgurl=")[1]
     urllib.urlretrieve(imgUrl, os.path.basename(imgUrl))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `soup.select('div[data-image]')` to select all `<div>` with `data-image=` attribute. Then loop over these divs and download them (for example with requests):

```
import requests

# ...

for img_number, div in enumerate(soup.select('div[data-image]'), 1):
    with open('image_{:>04d}.jpg'.format(img_number), 'wb') as f_out:
        f_out.write( requests.get(div['data-image']).content )
```